# cli command ng new not working for angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

Just updated my cli, npm, ng and nodejs to latest versions. An `ng v` gives this:

```
Angular CLI: 7.0.2
Node: 8.12.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.10.2
@angular-devkit/core         7.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics   7.0.2
@schematics/angular          7.0.2
@schematics/update           0.10.2
rxjs                         6.3.3
typescript                   3.1.3
```

Update old Angular 6 projects successfully also. However, upon issuing the command `ng new myproj`, I get the result:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"myproj"}
Errors:

  Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

The issue is so fresh there isn't how-to-fix online. Any help?

Comment: Looks like an issue with angular.json - maybe it didn't upgrade correctly? Maybe create a fresh project and compare.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do! I tried to create a fresh project using "ng new someproject" but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Good point - sorry I misread that bit.

Comment: I added an answer [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972168/schematic-input-does-not-validate-against-the-schema-nametestng7-on-angu/52974172#52974172).

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar sort of issue.I tried the following steps strictly:

```
Uninstall angular cli(npm uninstall -g @angular/cli)

Uninstall node.js from control panel/add or remove software option of your computer
```

->Delete npm and npm-cache folder manually from computer(These folders are in C:\Users\asus\AppData\Roaming,in your case
'Users' maybe your name and 'asus' maybe your computer manufacturers name)

->Re-install latest node.js version(select the option "npm as package manager" wile installing)

```
Run the command "npm i -g npm@latest" at powershell/gitbash
```

->Restart computer

```
Run "npm install -g @angular/cli" command

Run "ng config -g cli.packageManager npm" command

Run "npm cache verify" command(or npm cache clean --force if node version < 5)
```

Everything worked.

Comment: Good. You might also want to check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972168/schematic-input-does-not-validate-against-the-schema-nametestng7-on-angu/52974172#52974172