# Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"testng7"} on Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I updated the Angular CLI to the latest `@angular/cli@7.0.2` on a Mac OS.
When issuing the command `ng new testng7`, I get this error:

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"testng7"}
Errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

And nothing is created.

Any clues how to fix?

Comment: In my case, It was the '_' which was responsible for this error, After I changing it into '-' it works fine

Comment: a dot [.] does not work either..

Comment: this comment might help someone in future => if you have multiple projects in your angular app then add flag --client-project for example => ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --client-project=project-name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, to upgrade, I did this:

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
npm i @angular/cli
```

to install globally and locally. Running an `npm audit fix` revealed there is a problem with a missing `package.json` in the npm logs - missing from my root directory! So I created one with the following command in my home directory:

```
npm init --yes
```

for a default one. Now issuing an `ng new projName` works.

Answer (score 32):

**This error is possible of avoiding naming standards**

Project name can not have `underscore '_'`. It can have `dashes '-'`, `small` and `capital` letters and `digits`.

**Valid Project Names**

```
myProject //camel casing style or JavaScript style

MyProject //normal style

MyProject1 //letters and numbers mixed style

My-Project1 //letters, numbers and dash mixed style
```

**Invalid Project Names**

```
MyProject-1 //dash can not be between letter and digit

My_Project //underscore is restricted
```

Answer (score 12):

I added this flag to make it work `--client-project`

`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --client-project=launcher`

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem

```
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"DemoProj"}
Errors:
  Data path "" should have required property 'version'.
```

Do the following steps to resolve this issue

1. `npm uninstall -g angular-cli`
2. `npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli`
3. `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
4. `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest`
5. `npm install -g`
6. `ng new YourProjectName`

I hope it will work

Comment: I had a similar problem with Angular 8 when trying to `ng add` a package. This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try the

> ng new projectName

cmd in powershell with admin rights. I did it once and after that it works in normal cmd promt too.

Comment: I tried that first of course - but it causes the problem I described. I also wrote about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52920355/cli-command-ng-new-not-working-for-angular-7. It have now added the solution to my problem at least.

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem. I had the following property in my **Angular 16** project configuration:

`angular.json`

```json
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
     }
    }
```

after I changed "styleext" to "style" the component generation worked as expected.

Resulting `angular.json`:

```json
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
       "style": "scss"
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

none of the solutions helped me or does not deal with the root cause.
I found this in my angular.json

```
  "schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
  "styleext": "scss"
 }
}
```

Also my IDE was showing styletext property was not allowed. So I changed the above to this and it works.

```
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "skipTests": true
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was triggered due to an outdated global configuration for angular.

`.angular-config.json`

This file is usually located at the base user location

Windows:- `C:\Users\userName`

MAC:- `~`

Comment: Same for me. Had an old installation of Angular.

Came back and the config was causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the input provided to the schematic doesn't match the expected schema. In this case, the error indicates that the input is missing the required property 'project'.

When using Angular schematics, the ng generate command requires a project name to run schematics. Here's the correct syntax for generating a component named 'courses-card-list' with the style 'scss':

```
ng generate component courses-card-list --style=scss --project=<project-name>
```

Replace  with the name of your Angular project. This should resolve the validation error you're encountering.

Comment: This worked for me, overlooked it a couple of times

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes can be caused by wrong 'global' version of ng.

Try

```
npx ng generate component MyComponent
```

That will use 'local' ng installed into node_modules of project

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --project=Site
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to angular.json in that find **projects** under that find your project name inside that you will find **schematics** inside **schematics** replace **styleext** with **style**

also find **schematics** in angular.json and inside that also replace **styleext** with **style**

By doin this you problem will be solved **you won't have to upgrade your versions** and you can continue working in the same environment

Answer (score -1):

Try

> ng new testng7 --version=7.0.2

It Will Work!!!

Answer (score -1):

**100% works**

**Step 1:**  Just select your project working directory

**cd C:/AngularProjects**

**Step 2:** Then run

**ng new ProjectName**