# Using ng-new I'm getting "Schematic input does not validate against the Schema":

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

I'm getting the following error,

```
$ ng new ng_api_browser

Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"name":"ng_api_browser","version":"7.3.1","routing":true,"style":"sass"}
Errors:

  Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: How is my question a duplicate of that question? Look at the chosen answers of the two questions and stop being so quick to close. That question is about logs. my quesiton is about invalid characters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974172/124486

Comment: that question is specifically `Data path "" should have required property 'version'.` Mine is `Data path ".name" should match format "html-selector".`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the `_` is not valid in the project name. Use `-` instead.

Had you have done `ng new` and typed in `ng_api_browser` you would have seen ng reject it.